# Spring Batch Illegal state (only happens > on a race condition): job execution already running

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

In my Spring Batch application I use PostgreSQL as a job repository and the following login in order to restart the not completed jobs:

```
try {
    jobRegistry.register(new ReferenceJobFactory(documetPipelineJob));

    List<String> jobs = jobExplorer.getJobNames();
    for (String job : jobs) {

    Set<JobExecution> jobExecutions = jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(job);

    for (JobExecution jobExecution : jobExecutions) {

        jobExecution.setStatus(BatchStatus.STOPPED);
        jobExecution.setEndTime(new Date());
        jobRepository.update(jobExecution);

        Long jobExecutionId = jobExecution.getId();
        jobOperator.restart(jobExecutionId);
    }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

but this logic fails with the following exception:

> 2018-08-01 14:33:21.777 ERROR 32306 --- [main]
>   c.v.p.d.service.batch.BatchServiceImpl   : Illegal state (only happens
>   on a race condition): job execution already running with
>   name=documetPipelineJob and parameters=

what may be wrong here and how to fix it ?

**UPDATED**

looks like `jobRepository.update(jobExecution);` doesn't commit changes to the database. How to properly commit changes to the database? Btw - this logic worked fine with H2 in-memory database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve this issue I have added `incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())`:

```
jobBuilderFactory.get("documetPipelineJob")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .start(initStep)
```

I also extended the restart logic in order to stop running steps:

```
try {
    jobRegistry.register(new ReferenceJobFactory(documetPipelineJob));

    List<String> jobs = jobExplorer.getJobNames();
    for (String job : jobs) {

    Set<JobExecution> jobExecutions = jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(job);

    for (JobExecution jobExecution : jobExecutions) {

        Collection<StepExecution> stepExecutions = jobExecution.getStepExecutions();
        for (StepExecution stepExecution : stepExecutions) {
        BatchStatus status = stepExecution.getStatus();
        if (status.isRunning() || status == BatchStatus.STOPPING) {
            stepExecution.setStatus(BatchStatus.STOPPED);
            stepExecution.setEndTime(new Date());
            jobRepository.update(stepExecution);
        }
        }

        jobExecution.setStatus(BatchStatus.STOPPED);
        jobExecution.setEndTime(new Date());
        jobRepository.update(jobExecution);

        Long jobExecutionId = jobExecution.getId();

        jobOperator.restart(jobExecutionId);
    }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Then, I ran into the issue described in the following article: [Serialize Transaction Issue](https://ycj28c.github.io/database/2018/06/05/serialize-transaction-issue/) I run several batch jobs run at the same time.

I fixed it by configuring `JobRepository` with `ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED`:

```
@Override
protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
    JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    factory.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED");
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
}
```